# how to use scramble in production

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, scramble

I'm trying to document my laravel api and I'm using the scramble package. Locally everything works fine but in a production environment there's a bug (a 403 error when I access the page).

I followed the documentation and added a gate(The e-mail I'm showing you is just an example, to be on the safe side.)

```
Gate::define('viewApiDocs', function (User $user) {
  return in_array($user->email, ['test.test@test.test']);
});


<?php

namespace Dedoc\Scramble\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class RestrictedDocsAccess
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if (app()->environment('local')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if (Gate::allows('viewApiDocs')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403);
    }
}


//new middleware
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->session()->get('user');
        if (app()->environment('local')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if (!$user) {
            return redirect('login');
        }
        
        if (in_array($user->email, ["test.test@test.test"])) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403);
    }
```

and at the end I'd like to have my documentaion as in a local environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. php artisan vendor:publish
2. Select `scramble-config`
3. change `config/scramble.php` file - **middleware** section: *RestrictedDocsAccess::class* - override your class

**Package middleware**

```php
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
{

    if (app()->environment('local')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    if (Gate::allows('viewApiDocs')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    abort(403);
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class MyRestrictedDocsAccess
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if (app()->environment('local')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $user = $request->user();

        if (in_array($user->email, ['test.test@test.test'])) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403);
    }
}
```

`config/scramble.php`

```php
    'middleware' => [
        'web',
        \App\Http\Middleware\MyRestrictedDocsAccess::class,
    ],
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's already there but it keeps displaying a 403 in production. Note that your proposal is the default configuration.

Comment: I provided an example of how it works by default. You need to create your class in `app/Http/Middleware/MyRestrictedDocsAccess.php` and write your condition in the `handle` method + write the path to the MyRestrictedDocsAccess file you created in the `config/scramble.php` file

Comment: I've updated the answer, following your example

Comment: okay thanks, but I've got a new problem, I've adapted your logic a bit to suit mine (a user must first be logged in before having access to the documentation) and another error occurs, "Failed to parse OpenAPI file.Please make sure your OpenAPI file is valid and try again". so my logic is fine but I don't know what the problem is afterwards.let me change my original question so that you can see the logic

Comment: I would recommend that you use basic auth.

Nginx example
```php
location /docs/api.json {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Comment: in fact your answer was bone from the start, i just had to configure my ngnix so that it didn't consider /public/docs/api.json as a file but rather as a route. really thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In their docs, they say to define the viewApiDocs Gate to access the docs in production but don't say how to define the Gate.

**So how do you define the viewApiDocs Gate?**

To define a viewApiDocs Gate, the process is pretty simple. First, you need to go to your AuthServiceProvider and find your boot() method. In this method, you will define the Gate as follows:

```
   /**
     * Register any authentication/authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        Gate::define('viewApiDocs', function (User $user) {
            return in_array($user->email, ['test.test@test.test']);
        });
    }
```

Inside your Gate definition, you can do whatever you would like. If you want everyone to be able to access your API documentation, you can return true.

In the example you shared, you tried to implement the viewApiDocs Gate, but you were doing this outside of the AuthServiceProvider boot() method. **In order to make your gate properly work, you must define it inside the AuthServiceProvider boot method.**

If you define your Gate properly, you do NOT need to override the RestrictedDocAccess class.

Comment: in the end, the problem was with my ngnix configuration. thank you